# Rocker arm adjustment specs

Tags: engine, chevrolet, s10

Got a 98 s10 pickup 4.3L

Does anyone have the torque specs for the rocker arms on my truck, i been looking around and cant find any solid information.

Answer (score 2):

You don't find a torque spec because there isn't one. There's a *process* you must follow to adjust your rocker arms. Stock rocker arm nuts have an interference fit, which have a clamping force of their own on the rocker stud. They don't have a torque spec, because *they don't need a torque spec*.

I have already written the exact procedure to adjust the rocker arms/valve train for your GM 4.3L V6 engine [in your other question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/64405/4152), but I'll copy it again here so you have it:

To properly set the valves on a GM hydraulic tappet motor (assuming you don't have solid lifters on your engine), do the following:

1. Loosen all of the rocker arms so the push rods are loose
2. Find Top Dead Center (TDC) on the compression stroke for cylinder number 1 (both push rods should be even, if not, rotate crank another 360°)
3. With your fingers on the push rod, rotating it, tighten the rocker arm until the pushrod just stops turning, then tighten it 1/2 turn more (or 180°)
4. Do the same for the other rocker on the same cylinder
5. Turn the crank over ~120° and do the steps #2 & #3 for cylinder #6
6. Turn the crank over ~120° and do the steps #2 & #3 for cylinder #5
7. Turn the crank over ~120° and do the steps #2 & #3 for cylinder #4
8. Turn the crank over ~120° and do the steps #2 & #3 for cylinder #3
9. Turn the crank over ~120° and do the steps #2 & #3 for cylinder #2
10. Turn the crank over 360° to ensure the motor turns freely throughout the range

The idea is to have the lifters on the base circle of the cam when you adjust them. You can put your finger over the spark plug hole and know when the piston is coming up in the cylinder as air will push out past your finger. Do not use the starter to turn the engine over, but rather, use the crankshaft pulley bolt with a socket/ratchet.

Comment: Investing in a workshop manual may be a good idea...

Comment: @SolarMike - You are not wrong. Answering the questions *here* with a detailed approach is not wrong either ... and is how things are done on SE.

Comment: Having to answer them twice... same info - different posts to same person could, perhaps, be seen as a duplicate.

Comment: @SolarMike - The procedure is the same, but the question and the answer to the question are quite different.